# Wordpress and jQuery still no luck

Tags: jquery, wordpress, wordpress-theming

after reading everywhere about the proper way to use jQuery and Wordpress:
http://scribu.net/wordpress/optimal-script-loading.html
http://www.ericmmartin.com/5-tips-for-using-jquery-with-wordpress/

I came up with this code:

First the functions.php

```
add_action('init', 'deregister_wp_jq');
add_action('init', 'register_my_jquery');
add_action('init', 'enqueue_my_jquery');
add_action('init', 'register_my_scripts');
add_action('wp_footer', 'print_my_scripts');

function deregister_wp_jq () {
    wp_deregister_script('jquery');             
}

function register_my_jquery ()
{
    wp_register_script('my-jquery', "http" . ($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443 ? "s" : "") . "://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js", array(), '1.7.2', true);
    wp_register_script('my-jquery-ui', "http" . ($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443 ? "s" : "") . "://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.min.js", array('my-jquery'), '1.7.2', true);
}


function enqueue_my_jquery () {
    wp_enqueue_scripts('my-jquery');
    wp_enqueue_scripts('my-jquery-ui');
}


function register_my_scripts() {
    wp_register_script('setNavigation', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.setNavigation.js', array('my-jquery'), null, true);
    wp_register_script('spasticNav', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.spasticNav.mod.js', array('my-jquery', 'my-jquery-ui', 'setNavigation'), null, true);


}




function print_my_scripts() {
        wp_print_scripts('spasticNav');
        wp_print_scripts('setNavigation');
}
```

This is spasticNav, the plugin I want to use:

```
    // JavaScript Document
    (function($) {
        $.fn.spasticNav = function(options) {
            options = $.extend({
                overlap : 20,
                speed : 500,
                reset : 1500,
                color : '#b80606',
                easing : 'easeOutExpo'
            }, options);
            return this.each(function() {

                var nav = $(this), currentPageItem = $('#selected', nav), blob, reset;

                $('<li id="blob"></li>').css({
                    width : currentPageItem.outerWidth(),
                    height : currentPageItem.outerHeight() + options.overlap,
                    left : currentPageItem.position().left,
                    top : currentPageItem.position().top - options.overlap / 2,
                    backgroundColor : options.color
                }).appendTo(this);

                blob = $('#blob', nav);

                $('li:not(#blob)', nav).hover(function() {
                    // mouse over
                    clearTimeout(reset);
                    blob.animate({
                        left : $(this).position().left,
                        width : $(this).width()
                    }, {
                        duration : options.speed,
                        easing : options.easing,
                        queue : false
                    });
                });

            });
            // end each

        };

    })(jQuery); 

jQuery(function() 
        {
        jQuery("#nav").spasticNav();

        });
```

Then this is the jquery.setNavigation.js

```
function setNavigation() {
    var path = window.location.pathname;
    path = path.replace(/\/$/, "");
    path = decodeURIComponent(path);

    $(".nav a").each(function () {
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        if (path.substring(0, href.length) === href) {
            $(this).closest('li').addClass('active');
        }
    });
}

$(function () {
    setNavigation();
});
```

I got a headache, backache, whatever-ache, spent hours and hours to fix this, but still, it does not work.
Please, help me. I tried everything from different tutorials, etc., but nothing.

P.S.: I added the function to set the active state for

elements of the  (the menu), but it does not work yet.

----------------------------------------- UPDATE -------------------------------

OK, so after other 12 hours or so passed searching on Google and debugging the code, finally I found the problem.
It has to do with font-face as explained here:
[Lava Lamp navigation jQuery Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7145917/lava-lamp-navigation-problem-jquery-firefox)

This is the code that I am using now in functions.php

```
function my_scripts_method() { // Creates the my_scripts_method function
    wp_deregister_script('jquery'); // Deregisters the built-in version of jQuery
    wp_register_script('jquery', 'http' . ($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443 ? 's' : '') . '://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js', false, null, true); // Registers a CDN hosted version. If browsing on a secure connection, use HTTPS.
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery'); // Activates the jQuery script
    wp_register_script('jquery-ui', 'http' . ($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443 ? 's' : '') . '://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.min.js', false, null, true); // Registers a CDN hosted version. If browsing on a secure connection, use HTTPS.
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui'); // Activates the jQuery script

    wp_register_script('spasticNav', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.spasticNav.mod.js', false, null, true); // Registers your javascript file
    wp_enqueue_script('spasticNav'); // Actives your javascript file
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method'); // Tells WordPress to run the my_scripts_method function
```

And this is for the jquery.spasticNav.mod.js

```
// JavaScript Document
(function($) {
    jQuery.fn.spasticNav = function(options) {
        options = jQuery.extend({
            overlap : 20,
            speed : 500,
            reset : 1500,
            color : '#b80606',
            easing : 'easeOutExpo'
        }, options);
        return this.each(function() {

            var nav = jQuery(this), currentPageItem = jQuery('#selected', nav), blob, reset;

            jQuery('<li id="blob"></li>').css({
                width : currentPageItem.outerWidth(),
                height : currentPageItem.outerHeight() + options.overlap,
                left : currentPageItem.position().left,
                top : currentPageItem.position().top - options.overlap / 2,
                backgroundColor : options.color
            }).appendTo(this);

            blob = jQuery('#blob', nav);

            jQuery('li:not(#blob)', nav).hover(function() {
                // mouse over
                clearTimeout(reset);
                blob.animate({
                    left : jQuery(this).position().left,
                    width : jQuery(this).width()
                }, {
                    duration : options.speed,
                    easing : options.easing,
                    queue : false
                });
            });

        });
        // end each

    };

})(jQuery); 

jQuery(function() {
    jQuery.noConflict();
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    document.onreadystatechange = function () {  
    if (document.readyState == "complete") {
    jQuery('#nav').spasticNav();}}});});
```

This is the error:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'left' of null

and it refers to these statements:

```
left : currentPageItem.position().left,
top : currentPageItem.position().top - options.overlap / 2
```

I hope you can help me now that i pinpointed the issue.

--------------------------------- UPDATE 2 - FIXED -----------------------------------

OK, it turns out that in the static version of the website, To feed something selected to spasticNav, I used:

```
<li> <a href="#acasa" id="selected">Acasa</a> </li>
```

WP provides already a script that changes automatically the status and it does so by adding the class .current_page_item
Therefore, I modified this line accordingly:

```
var nav = jQuery(this), currentPageItem = jQuery('#selected', nav), blob, reset;

var nav = jQuery(this), currentPageItem = jQuery('.current_page_item', nav), blob, reset;
```

Comment: is there any error in the console? and what is not working

Comment: Can you tell us what is wrong/not working? It is not clear from the question. You have just dumped your code.

Comment: I cannot see the effect that you can appreciate on the author's page: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/how-to-build-a-lava-lamp-style-navigation-menu/    This on the static version of the website that I made works properly.

Comment: I cannot see any php error popping up.

Comment: I checked again and this time I have enabled also the script debugging feature in wp and there was an error with wrong link to jquery-ui like: http://localhost/wordpresshttp://... which of course was wrong. I fixed it setting jquery-ui locally. Now there are no errors, but still, it doesn't work. :(

Comment: Now in the console I see this nice error with the solution provided by Chris Fernandi: SCRIPT5009: '$' is undefined 
wordpress, line 63 character 19

Answer (score 0):

You don't need that many functions and actuons to make this work. Try this: http://gomakethings.com/jquery-wordpress/

Answer (score 0):

Even though you said you want to use the proper way to use jQuery, you're not doing it properly at all. What you'll need in your `functions.php` is this:

```
wp_register_script('jquery');
```

Other than that you won't need anything at all, you'll only have to remember that jQuery in WordPress is in noConflict mode. So always start your scripts with `jQuery` rather than `$`.