# Debugging PhantomJS @font-face issues

Tags: css, node.js, amazon-ec2, font-face, phantomjs

When I render webpages with PhantomJS using Node.js on an EC2 server, I have trouble loading fonts. I have looked this problem up on Google and while people are having issues with this, none of the solutions really helped me. What I am looking for is a method for debugging PhantomJS and @font-face. I want to see what font files it is trying to load and where the problem might be occurring so I can **fix it myself**. Obviously this is very vague so here are some images detailing my problem:

Rendered on localhost (fonts are installed on the machine): https://i.stack.imgur.com/fsT5G.jpg
Rendered on EC2 (fonts should be loaded from an external css file): https://i.stack.imgur.com/PM1uH.jpg

Comment: We ran into the same issue and we solved it by installing the custom font on the EC2 server (headless Ubuntu). Another possible solution is to use an SVG font in your CSS instead of a TTF or OTF.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is pretty easy: You're rendering the image before the FOUT is resolved.

Check this: [How to know when font-face has been applied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6677181/how-to-know-when-font-face-has-been-applied)