# Javascript: when is the font-face applied?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

We have an application where:

- Apply font-face `Lato` to body
- Need to calculate `offset().top` value of some elements (for scroll-spy)

Now we calculate the value of `offset().top` in an Angular `link` function, which should be invoked after DOM is ready.

However, we found that the values are inaccurate. If we disable the font `Lato`, the values become correct.

So we suspect that in the `link` function, when we calculate, the font is not yet rendered to the `body`, making the `offset()` value incorrect.

How can we calculate only after the font is applied?

I have tried the solution given in [How to know when font-face has been applied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6677181/how-to-know-when-font-face-has-been-applied), but without luck.

Comment: Have you tried to put the calculations in `link` inside zero-delay `$timeout`? Can't promise it will work for font-face, but it helps in similar cases.

Comment: Maybe `line-height` has some effect for calculating offset?

Comment: Thanks @estus. But i tried, it does not work. And `line-height` is set to be `24px` for the whole wrapper, @Justinas.

Comment: Please show an example that replicates the problem. It's impossible to say what could be wrong with your code without seeing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, we had exactly the same problem at work. We integrated a webfont loader to avoid this behavior. I think the most famous one is this one:
https://github.com/typekit/webfontloader (developed by Google and Typekit)

You will have events for the state of the fonts to load. For example "active", when all fonts have rendered. You can bind JavaScript callback to this events, so you can start calculations after fonts are applied.